# "TypeError: 'Polygon' object is not iterable" when looping through overlapping polygons in Python

Tags: python, polygon, geopandas, intersection, overlapping-features

I refer to this example notebook resource that shows how to identify intersection regions between polygons:
https://nbviewer.org/gist/jorisvandenbossche/3a55a16fda9b3c37e0fb48b1d4019e65

Here in this example, with credit going to the author of that example notebook above, we start with 3 circles that happen to all overlap:

[image]

We then try to find all of the new intersected polygons made up by these overlapping polygons via this code:

```py
all_intersections = [a.intersection(b) for a, b in list(itertools.combinations(s, 2))]
s_all = pd.concat([s, geopandas.GeoSeries(all_intersections)])
polys = list(shapely.ops.polygonize(s_all.boundary.unary_union))
polys = geopandas.GeoSeries(polys)
polys.plot(cmap='Set1')
```

to get this plot of our three overlapping circles with each new intersected polygon identified, and so we now have 7 polygons identified, just what I want:

[image]

And then just running `polys` I see the geometries for each of these 7 newly intersected polygons printed, great:

[image]

Though what I am trying to figure out how to do is how to loop through each unique polygon in the initial GeoDataFrame and identify only the polygon intersections within that specific polygon.

So going with this new example:

[image]

For circle A would just get the geometry for circle A itself returned, and then for circle B, I would just get the intersections within circle B returned:

[image]

And for circle E, I would get just the intersections within circle E returned:

[image]

And so on, repeating this process for each unique circle.

How can I augment my above polygon intersection code to accommodate a `for` loop to iterate through each unique circle and only identify the intersected polygons within that specific polygon?

I have tried this:

```py
for index, row in polygons.iterrows():
    
    all_intersections = [a.intersection(b) for a, b in list(itertools.combinations(row['geometry'], 2))]
    polygons_all = pd.concat([polygons, gpd.GeoSeries(all_intersections)])
    polys = list(shapely.ops.polygonize(polygons_all.boundary.unary_union))
    polys = gpd.GeoSeries(polys)
```

but am just getting errors, specifically:

> TypeError: 'Polygon' object is not iterable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am no expert on GeoPandas, not having used it *all* that much, so my adaptation of the code in your question may not be the cleanest or most efficient but, testing on a made-up data set, this seems to do what you are after:

```py
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
import itertools
import shapely

# Path to your polygons file
shp_path = '/home/path/to/polygons.shp'
gdf = gpd.read_file(shp_path)
gdf.boundary.plot()

def get_intersections(i):
    # Current polygon
    current = gdf.iloc[i]
    # All other polygons with current dropped
    others = gdf.drop(i)
    # Get all other intersections with current
    ix = [current.geometry.intersection(other) for other in others.geometry if current.geometry.intersects(other)]
    if ix:
        s = pd.concat([gpd.GeoSeries(current.geometry), gpd.GeoSeries(ix)])
        # Get all combinations of intersections
        all_ix = [a.intersection(b) for a, b in list(itertools.combinations(s, 2))]
        return pd.concat([gpd.GeoSeries(current.geometry), gpd.GeoSeries(all_ix)])
    else:
        return gpd.GeoSeries(current.geometry)


for i in range(gdf.shape[0]):
    s = get_intersections(i)
    polys = list(shapely.ops.polygonize(s.boundary.unary_union))
    polys = gpd.GeoSeries(polys)
    polys.plot(cmap='Set2')
```

Resulting plots:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello thanks for this incredible suggestion, you totally understand what I was going for here! Though in trying our your code on my polygons, where some overlap with others, and some do not overlap at all, on the line `s = get_intersections(i)` I receive this error message: `TypeError: 'method' object is not iterable`. Do you know why that would be since it seems totally fine to me that I would "iterate" over each row in my geodataframe to run the `get_intersections` function on each unique polygon. I know that this error means I am iterating over a "method", but I don't see why I get this.

Comment: @LostinSpatialAnalysis, I'm not sure. Did you modify the script? Would you be able to share your shapefile so that I could test it?

Comment: Actually I just fixed it, just had to tidy up my code a bit, your code suggestion works great! Thank you very much!

Comment: @LostinSpatialAnalysis, great! Glad it's working.

Comment: I was wondering, is there perhaps a way to augment this code suggestion so that for each buffer polygon that gets intersected there is a unique ID corresponding to each intersection zone? I have an underlying raster layer, and I am just trying to find a way so that I can loop through each unique buffer polygon and find the average raster pixel value for each uniquely intersected zone. I am just trying to figure out how I should go forward with using your code suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: To clarify my point there, when I look at the `polys` dataframes for each iteration through the loop, I see a geometry listed for each intersection zone, which is what I want, but all that is contained in `polys` is the geometry, and no column indicating the original IDs of each original polygon that "contributed" to each intersection zone. For instance, looking at the second intersected polygon in your output above, looking at the tan section, what original polygons made up this intersection zone? And which original polygons made up the blue section? etc. That is what I meant to say. Thanks!

Comment: @LostinSpatialAnalysis, I will try to have a look later.

Comment: Thank you very much!